# Fill in the previous value from specific column based on a condition

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a Polars DataFrame that looks something like so:

```py
d = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'val': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        'count': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
        'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    }
)
```

What I need is to create a new column `'prev_val'` which will contain values for the same unique id taken from a row where the value in `'count'` column is smaller by one, i.e. looking something like:

```py
r = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'val': [9, 7, 9, 11, 2, 5],
        'count': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
        'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        'prev_val': [None, 9, None, 9, None, 2]
    }
)
```

I couldn't figure a way of using native expressions so I tried doing this using a UDF, even though Polars guide discourages the use of UDFs:

```py
# for a UDF find indices for necessary columns
cols = df.columns
search_cols = ['val', 'count', 'id']
col_idx = {col: cols.index(col) for col in search_cols}

def get_previous_value(row):
    count = row[col_idx['count']]
    id_ = row[col_idx['id']]
    
    # get the previous count, id remains the same
    prev_count = count - 1
    
    # return the value for the previous count for the same id
    return df.filter(pl.all((pl.col('count') == prev_count), pl.col('id') == id_)).select('val').first()
```

But when I try and apply a function I get a confusing error:

```
res = d.apply(lambda x: get_previous_value(x))

Out:
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `2`,
 right: `1`: impl error', /home/runner/work/polars/polars/polars/polars-core/src/series/iterator.rs:70:9
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PanicException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[59], line 2
----> 2 res = d.apply(lambda x: get_previous_value(x))

File ~/python/f1_car_following/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/dataframe/frame.py:5388, in DataFrame.apply(self, function, return_dtype, inference_size)
   5302 def apply(
   5303     self,
   5304     function: Callable[[tuple[Any, ...]], Any],
   (...)
   5307     inference_size: int = 256,
   5308 ) -> Self:
   5309     """
   5310     Apply a custom/user-defined function (UDF) over the rows of the DataFrame.
   5311 
   (...)
   5386 
   5387     """
-> 5388     out, is_df = self._df.apply(function, return_dtype, inference_size)
   5389     if is_df:
   5390         return self._from_pydf(out)

PanicException: assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `2`,
 right: `1`: impl error
```

What am I doing wrong here? It looks to me that the assertion is checking whether the return value is a dataframe and I don't uderstand why it should be so...

Is there maybe a native way to do this?

Comment: What version of polars are you using? Your example raises `TypeError: all() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given` for me, which if we fix, then raises `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'first'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a `.join`.

You could use `.unique` with `keep="last"` to generate your search space.

```
(df.with_columns(pl.col("count") + 1)
   .unique(
      subset=["id", "count"], 
      keep="last",
      maintain_order=True
))
```

```
df.join(
   df.with_columns(pl.col("count") + 1)
     .unique(subset=["id", "count"], keep="last", maintain_order=True)
     .select("id", "count", prev_val = "val"),
   on=["id", "count"],
   how="left"
)
```

```
shape: (6, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ val ┆ count ┆ id  ┆ prev_val │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64      │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 9   ┆ 1     ┆ 1   ┆ null     │
│ 7   ┆ 2     ┆ 1   ┆ 9        │
│ 9   ┆ 1     ┆ 2   ┆ null     │
│ 11  ┆ 2     ┆ 2   ┆ 9        │
│ 2   ┆ 1     ┆ 3   ┆ null     │
│ 5   ┆ 2     ┆ 3   ┆ 2        │
└─────┴───────┴─────┴──────────┘
```

df used:

```
df = pl.from_repr("""
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬─────┐
│ val ┆ count ┆ id  │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════╡
│ 9   ┆ 1     ┆ 1   │
│ 7   ┆ 2     ┆ 1   │
│ 9   ┆ 1     ┆ 2   │
│ 11  ┆ 2     ┆ 2   │
│ 2   ┆ 1     ┆ 3   │
│ 5   ┆ 2     ┆ 3   │
└─────┴───────┴─────┘
""")
```